# How to count userhits with redis?

Tags: redis

mayby I am doin something completely useless to create my datasets at all. I incr keys to a user-tracking with

```
incr('userhit-by-day:20131118') //for the day
incr('userhit-by-day-and-userid:20131118:foobar123') //for the day and userid
```

How can I get a hit counter like top 10 users by from today, this week and a special date?

Comment: You need sorted set for this task.

Answer (score 1):

make use of "Sorted set" as per above comment.

[here](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) is documentation

Create a set for every day, 
In that set, key should be UserId and its value should be count of hits.

Use `ZINCRBY key increment member` to update user's hit count.

Using `ZREVRANGE key start stop [WITHSCORES]` you can get list of all players who hit that day.

Using `ZSCORE key member` you can get particular users hit count.